# How to add scrollbar in Groupbox MFC

Tags: mfc, scrollbar, groupbox

I have a groupbox which contains text boxes. I want more text boxes with in the same groupbox with out increasing the size of groupbox, If this groupBox has scroll it will be easy to achieve this. How to add scrollbar to Groupbox?

Answer (score 0):

My MFC days are a while ago and a bit rusty, but from what I remember this isn't possible, but you can emulate this by placing a borderless, child dialog within the group box and then place your text boxes onto that.